# In magento unable to get the image url thorugh the REST URL

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento

I am using magento to get the list of products through the REST url as localhost/magento/api/rest/products. In this list i am getting the image_url node. but when i give the image url as localhost/magento/api/rest/products/166/images, it shows "magento_api/".. Thats it. No more information about the image url..

So how can i get the image details through the URL??

Comment: can you confirm the images are  uploaded  in magento admin backend?

Comment: yes... but i am getting the details of only one image.. but for the same product there are four images in the database..how can i get all the image url's?

Comment: If images are there then, it should shows three images,http://postimage.org/image/6zt1aih1t/, and aslo confirm the other images are selected or not check this...http://postimage.org/image/5nhcwm0j1/

Comment: yes.. In rest client it shows..but when i give the same query in my php code, it shows only one

Comment: how are you running the php scripts can u share plz

Comment: can we move to chat room??it will be better i think

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22571/discussion-between-chanz-and-pavankumar)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If images are there then, it should shows three images,[here](http://postimage.org/image/6zt1aih1t), and aslo confirm the other images are selected or not check this...[admin panel](http://postimage.org/image/5nhcwm0j1)

also refer this to upload images in product [wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-products)

Comment: In my case I get the image URL but not the full path `{
      "attribute_code": "image",
      "value": "/p/w/pwp_sheet2.jpeg"
    },`